# how do I get words with meta expressions from string regardless of spacing

Tags: python, regex

What I want to do is getting start point of some words from string.

For example,

```
context = "abcd e f g ( $ 150 )"
answer = "g($150)"
```

I want to get the start index of answer from context which should be "9".

I tried something like this,

```
answer = ' ?'.join()
try:
  answer = re.sub('[$]', '\$', answer)
  answer = re.sub('[(]', '\(', answer)
  answer = re.sub('[)]', '\)', answer)
except:
  pass
start_point = re.search(answer, context).span()[0]
```

Because there are answers with meta expressions and answers without meta expressions I used try, except.

And I used this kinds of code,

```
answer = re.sub('[(]', '\(', answer)
```

because if I don't use it, I found that re.search(answer, context) can't find my answer from context.

then I get this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mc_answer_v2.py", line 42, in <module>
    match = re.search(spaced_answer_text, mc_paragraph_text)
  File "/home/hyelchung/data1/envs/albert/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/home/hyelchung/data1/envs/albert/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/home/hyelchung/data1/envs/albert/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/home/hyelchung/data1/envs/albert/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/home/hyelchung/data1/envs/albert/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/home/hyelchung/data1/envs/albert/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 619, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
sre_constants.error: multiple repeat at position 3
```

How do I fix it and is there any other good way to get the start index?

Comment: This could be very tricky, because there is no obvious rule for when whitespace should or should not be present.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Does it mean that there would be no fancy way to solve that kind of problem? I hope someone could help me solving this problem.

Comment: Well, the obvious first attempt is to remove whitespace from the input, and then match on that.  But then, the indices we get back won't correlate with the original string.  Really, I consider this to be fairly bad data.  Try to fix the data at the source if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems possible to do it by sticking `\s*` (variable number of white space characters) after each escaped character of `answer` string.

```
import re
def findPosition(context, answer):
    regex=r"\s*"
    regAnswer=regex.join([re.escape(w) for w in answer]) + regex
    # print(regAnswer)
    return re.search(regAnswer, context).start()

context = "abcd e f g ( $ 150 )"
answer = "g($150)"

print(findPosition(context, answer))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map to escape each character
Regex replace the original string with the target string
The string find method looks for the target string. If the target string does not exist, it will not return -1 abnormally.

```
>>> import re
>>> context = 'abcd e f g ( $ 150 )'
>>> answer = 'g($150)'
>>> findSpacing = lambda target, src :re.sub("\s*".join(map(re.escape, target)), target, src).find(target)
>>> findSpacing(answer, context)
9
>>> findSpacing("FLAG", context)
-1
>>>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. Code-only answers are usually frowned upon around here.